# wildfly maven plugin domain deploy

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jboss, wildfly

pom.xml

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.Beta1</version>
            <configuration>
                <domain>
                  <server-groups>
                     <server-group>main-server-group</server-group>
                  </server-groups>
                </domain>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

in eclipse Run configurations is

```
org.wildfly.plugins:wildfly-maven-plugin:run -Dwildfly.version=8.0.0.CR1
```

my question is why the domain path below is empty

```
{$path of pom.xml}\target\wildfly-run\wildfly-8.0.0.CR1\domain\tmp
```

but the path of standalone

```
{$path of pom.xml}\target\wildfly-run\wildfly-8.0.0.CR1\standalone\tmp\vfs\temp\tempd2a5c6044ecaf908\content-b94122b24d483bc5\***(xxx.war files unzip here)
```

I mean,the official guide https://docs.jboss.org/wildfly/plugins/maven/latest/examples/deployment-example.html of the pom.xml configurations is to deploy and run the xxx.war to domain servers,why the commands above doesn't work,did I miss something?

Comment: well,I checked the source code and guide more carefully,the mvn wildfly:run or mvn wildfly:start just start the server in the standalone mode,check:https://docs.jboss.org/wildfly/plugins/maven/latest/run-mojo.html  
https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly-maven-plugin/blob/master/plugin/src/main/java/org/wildfly/plugin/server/RunMojo.java 
https://docs.jboss.org/wildfly/plugins/maven/latest/start-mojo.html 
 https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly-maven-plugin/blob/master/plugin/src/main/java/org/wildfly/plugin/server/StartMojo.java

Answer (score 0):

The `run` goal only works with a standalone server. It will not launch a domain server. If you want to deploy your application to existing domain server that is already running you need to use the `deploy` goal.